# npm build is failing after of yarn update

Tags: node.js, electron, yarnpkg

The npm start failing in all the application after the yarn update.
The logged error is:

```
 fs.js:159
 throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK();
 ^

 TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
 at maybeCallback (fs.js:159:9)
 at Object.fs.writeFile (fs.js:1278:14)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, I have to uninstall the yarn from the system and degrade the node version to make it work.

Comment: I was getting this error while trying to run v8.XXX node code with v10.XXX